# How to transform received data from @apollo/react-hooks

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I am using `` query:

```
const GET_COMMENTS = gql`
    query getComments {
        getComments (where: {code: "/about-us" }) {
            id
            text
            createdAt
        }
    }
`
....
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_COMMENTS);
```

in my code...

The code is fetching comments from the server in comment object is a `date: string!` property, I would like to transform this `date: string!` into javascript date (`new Date(comment.date)`) how can I do it directly after data fetch?

I don't want to transform every render is called.

Is there any something like this?:

```
const { loading, error, data } = 
   useQuery(
      GET_COMMENTS, 
      {
         transform: (data) => data.map(comment => ({...comment , date: new Date(comment.date)}) )
      }
   );
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [merge function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#the-merge-function) in cache type policies is what you are looking for. It allows you to define a custom strategy for writing incoming data into the cache.

When creating the cache you can define how to write specific fields. Let's assume the `date` field belongs to the `Comment` type:

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Comment: {
      fields: {
        date: {
          merge(_, date) {
            return new Date(date);
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_COMMENTS, {
  onCompleted: data => {
    // Do changes here
  }
});
```

You can check it here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/

Comment: `onCompleted` is not transforming the data, it just a callback wich is called after request is completed.

Comment: yes, onCompleted is not transforming the data. you need to do it after receiving the data

Answer (score 0):

You can call your transformer function inside `onCompleted` and use its result as a state variable.

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
const { loading } = useQuery(GET_DATA_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    options: {
      limit: 20
    }
  },
  onCompleted: (response) => {
    const transformed = tranformData(response)
    setMyData(transformed)
  }
});

return (
  <div style={{ color: "white" }}>
    {loading ? <div>Loading..</div> : <div>{myData.length}</div>}
  </div>
);
```